# Определить сколько каналов у png изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, png

Нужно определить сколько каналов у png изображения
Но не совсем представляю, как это сделать

Comment: прочитать спецификацию формата для начала

Comment: и почитать документацию к библиотеке, на которой вы планируете работать с PNG